# Create a generic ViewModifier for FocusState

Tags: swiftui

I was wondering how would I be able to create a generic View Modifier for a FocusState. So I am trying to create a modifier to dismiss the keyboard by making my FocusState = nil. Now I was able to create a modifier but it only works for one enum. How would I be able to make it generic so it can work with more than one enum.

This is how my code looks like.

```
enum First {
    case name
}

enum Second {
    case lastName
}

struct ResignFocusedField: ViewModifier {
    var focusField: FocusState<First?>.Binding // How would I change this...
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onTapGesture {
                focusField.wrappedValue = nil
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func resignFocusedField(_ ff: FocusState<First?>.Binding) -> some View {
        modifier(ResignFocusedField(focusField: ff))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no way to represents "only enums" with generics. You'll have to work with all `Hashable`s or adopt a marker protocol.
2. There is no need to create a view modifier if you don't need a new [`DynamicProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty).

```swift
extension View {
  func defocusOnTap<Value>(_ focusField: FocusState<Value?>.Binding) -> some View {
    onTapGesture {
      focusField.wrappedValue = nil
    }
  }
}
```